# PayPal IPN: Delivery status Disabled

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Why does the IPN not get sent? In my IPN history it says my last IPN attempt is N/A and the delivery status of each one is: Disabled.

On the PayPal website it says:

> Disabled indicates that the message will not be resent because the
>   merchant's account has been disabled

My account is not disabled though. I can send and receive money without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It was saying your account was disabled, but the IPN was
2. If you just enabled the IPN and inserted the URL, verify IPN is functional
3. [Use this reference to test your IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/)
4. [In-deph IPN Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/)
5. Make sure your listener sends an HTTP 200 OK response to each IPN it receives from PayPal.IPN delays occur if your listener fails to send an HTTP 200 OK response for too many IPNs. This happens because PayPal re-sends each IPN for which it does not receive an HTTP 200 OK response. Once a certain number of re-sends are in progress, your IPNs are moved to a slower-cycling server, which produces the delays and even disablement of your IPN in your paypal account

Answer (score 0):

There was a setting in my account that had my IPN set to disabled, even though it was still specified in my button parameters.